# how to send ascii value as option 43 (VCI) in dnsmasq?

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

I want to send a number as a string in DHCP Ack for vendor class matching say="Prash" , how do i send effectively?

Im using dnsmasq and i tried putting an option in dnsmasq.conf file as following

dhcp-option=vendor:Prash,1,403

This will match for all vendor class matching "Prash" and adds option 43 VCI in dhcp ack with 403.

In wireshark im however getting a random value, Can anyone suggest how exactly to send ASCII value as "403"?

Wireshark :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reply with option 43 , you must use **43** in the first field not **1**

dhcp-option=vendor:Prash,43,"403"

From
http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html

And for more technical details :

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3925

Comment: I am actually getting vci in dhcp ack but the value is different than what im expecting. I am attaching screenshot from my wireshark capture of dhcp ack

Comment: I tried by keeping the option u suggested and im getting the VCI value in wireshark as : 2b:03:34:30:33:ff , out of this 03:34:30:33 part corresponts to ascii value of "403" correctly, 2b means (43) option code we are passing and ff may be just end dilimiter ?